# Conversion from class to identical class with different template types

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, template-specialization

I have the simple class "vec2". I would like this class to be able to store doubles and double references in the class template, or even int and int references. Here is the desired behavior-

```
vec2<double> base(5, 5);  //normal vec2
vec2<double&> reference(base.x, base.y);  //vec2 reference to vec2 "base"
vec2<double> third;

base.x++; //base.x equals 6, this also changes reference.x to 6;
third = reference; //conversion between vec2<double> and vec2<double&>
```

I would also like modifying a reference instance of vec2 to be impossible, except by changing the variables it is referencing- so the following code would give a compiler error

```
vec2<double&> reference(base.x, base.y);  //vec2 reference to vec2 "base"
reference.x = 5; //undesired behaviour
```

Is there a way to make the members x and y public when dealing with non-reference class types, but private when the class type is a reference? This would require methods specific to when it is a reference that will return the  values of x and y. In the reference version it would also need to not have the overloaded operator methods that can affect the references. I slightly understand template specialization, but not enough to actually implement it.

Anyways, the main point of this is to find out how to take a class of type `vec2<double>`, and convert it to a class of type `vec2<double&>`.

Or, conversely, take a class of type `vec2<double&>`, and convert it to a class of type `vec2<double>`.

Here is my simple vec2 class-

```
template <class T> class vec2{
public:
    vec2(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    vec2(T X, T Y){
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
    void normalize(){   //this function should inaccesable to any "reference version" of vec2
        *this /= magnitude();
    }
    void rotate(double radians, vec2 center){   //this should also be inaccesable to reference versions
        vec2 ogPts = *this -= center;
        x = ogPts.x*cos(radians) - ogPts.y*sin(radians);
        y = ogPts.y*cos(radians) + ogPts.x*sin(radians);
        *this += center;
    }
    double magnitude() const{
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);  //this should be available to both
    }
    T x;
    T y;
    vec2 operator+(const vec2 &v) const{  //available to both
        return vec2(x+v.x, y+v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator-(const vec2 &v) const{ //available to both
        return vec2(x-v.x, y-v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(const vec2 &v) const{ //available to both

        return vec2(x*v.x, y*v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(T v) const{ //available to both, but should work even if v is not a reference variable and T is a reference
        return vec2(x*v, y*v);
    }
    vec2 operator/(T v) const{ //available to both, but should work even if v is not a reference variable and T is a reference
        return vec2(x/v, y/v);
    }
    vec2 operator+=(const vec2 &v){ //inaccesable to reference versions of the class
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator-=(const vec2 &v){ //inaccesable to reference versions
        x -= v.x;
        y -= v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator*=(const vec2 &v){ //inaccesable to reference versions
        x *= v.x;
        y *= v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator*=(T v){ //inaccesable to reference versions
        x *= v;
        y *= v;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator/=(T v){ //inaccesable to reference versions
        x /= v;
        y /= v;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const vec2 &v) const{ //this should be available to both
        return (v.x == x && v.y == y);
    }
    bool operator!=(const vec2 &v) const{ //this should be available to both
        return (v.x != x || v.y != y);
    }
};
```

Any help is much appreciated! I haven't worked with templates much, in fact, I just started yesterday! Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: It sounds like your reference type should be a different class template altogether. It's pretty confusing to me that `vec2<T>` would have public or private data members and different functionality depending on what `T` is. Maybe make a `vec2ref<T>`? Or better yet, get rid of it and just use a `const vec2<T>&`

Comment: @Kevin I don’t think it should be a different class... that seems quite ugly. Is it not possible to implement different methods for different template types? And it would be nice to be able to use vec2<double> and vec2<double&> interchangeably.  I don’t think that const vec2<double>& does quite what I’m looking for, because I want to be able to use any reference types as the x and y members, and const vec2<double>& would only allow a reference for a vec2<double>. What if I wanted to use int x and int y as references? It’d be impossible to do it in one step like you could with vec2<double&>.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research, and managed to learn a lot on template specialization. Here is the functioning vec2 class which implements everything I wanted, plus a "perpindiculate" function and a "swap" function-

```
template <class T> class vec2{
public:
    vec2(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    vec2(T X, T Y){
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
    operator vec2<T&>(){
        return vec2<T&>(x, y);
    }
    void swap(){
        std::swap(x, y);
    }
    void perpindiculate(){
        std::swap(x, y);
        y = -y;
    }
    void normalize(){
        *this /= magnitude();
    }
    void rotate(double radians, vec2 center){
        vec2 ogPts = *this -= center;
        x = ogPts.x*cos(radians) - ogPts.y*sin(radians);
        y = ogPts.y*cos(radians) + ogPts.x*sin(radians);
        *this += center;
    }
    double magnitude() const{
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
    vec2 operator+(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x+v.x, y+v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator-(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x-v.x, y-v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x*v.x, y*v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(T v) const{
        return vec2(x*v, y*v);
    }
    vec2 operator/(T v) const{
        return vec2(x/v, y/v);
    }
    vec2 operator+=(const vec2 &v){
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator-=(const vec2 &v){
        x -= v.x;
        y -= v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator*=(const vec2 &v){
        x *= v.x;
        y *= v.y;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator*=(T v){
        x *= v;
        y *= v;
        return *this;
    }
    vec2 operator/=(T v){
        x /= v;
        y /= v;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const vec2 &v) const{
        return (v.x == x && v.y == y);
    }
    bool operator!=(const vec2 &v) const{
        return (v.x != x || v.y != y);
    }
    T x;
    T y;
};

template<class T>
class vec2<T&>{
public:
    vec2(T& X, T& Y) : x{X}, y{Y} {}
    operator vec2<T>(){
        return vec2<T>(x, y);
    }
    vec2<T> swap() const{
        return vec2<T>(y, x);
    }
    vec2<T> perpindiculate() const{
        return vec2<T>(-y, x);
    }
    vec2<T> normalize() const{
        return *this / magnitude();
    }
    vec2<T> rotate(double radians, vec2 center) const{
        return vec2<T>(x*cos(radians) - y*sin(radians), y*cos(radians) + x*sin(radians));
    }
    double magnitude() const{
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
    vec2 operator+(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x+v.x, y+v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator-(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x-v.x, y-v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(const vec2 &v) const{
        return vec2(x*v.x, y*v.y);
    }
    vec2 operator*(T& v) const{
        return vec2(x*v, y*v);
    }
    vec2 operator/(T& v) const{
        return vec2(x/v, y/v);
    }
    bool operator==(const vec2 &v) const{
        return (v.x == x && v.y == y);
    }
    bool operator!=(const vec2 &v) const{
        return (v.x != x || v.y != y);
    }
    T getx(){
        return x;
    }
    T gety(){
        return y;
    }
private:
    T& x;
    T& y;
};
```

Here is an example of it working-

```
double x = 5;  //create future reference variables
double y = 3;
vec2<double&> vecref(x, y); //create vec2 referring to x and y
x = 7; //change x and y values, also changing vecref's values as well
y = 8;
vec2<double> vecOffRef = vecref; //conversion from a reference vec to a normal one
vec2<double&> vecOffRefref = vecOffRef; //conversion from a normal vec to a reference one
vecOffRef.normalize(); //normalize vec, also normalizing vecOffRefref

/* x equals 7, y = 8
   vecRef equals (7, 8)
   vecOffRef equals (0.6585, .7525)
   vecOffRefRef equals (0.6585, .7525) */
```

Answer (score -2):

A simplified version. By making the fields private, they can't be modified. I didn't try implementing all the operator= methods, but your code should work.

I'm not quite sure where your confusion is. A scan didn't see any problems, except I'd make the fields private so no one can touch them, and add accessor methods instead.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyClass {
private:
    T x;
    T y;

public:
    MyClass(T _x, T _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    T getX() const { return x; }
    T getY() const { return y; }
};

int main(int, char **) {
    double x {1.0};
    double y {2.5};

    MyClass<double> withDouble(x, y);
    MyClass<double &> withRef{x, y};

    cout << "withDouble: " << withDouble.getX() << ", " << withDouble.getY() << endl;
    cout << "withRef: " << withRef.getX() << ", " << withRef.getY() << endl;

    x = 3.9;
    y = 5.4;
    cout << "withRef: " << withRef.getX() << ", " << withRef.getY() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What I’m asking is that I need a conversion between vec2<double> and vec2<double&>... is this possible?